# How to check a uiviewcontroller is present in uinavigationcontroller stack

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, stack, nsmutablearray

I have a `UINavigationController`. I have to pop a view from a `UINavigationController` and replace it with another view. How we can search for a `UIViewController` object and replace it with another ?

when i print

```
NSMutableArray *allViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:           myDelegate.navigationController.viewControllers];
```

I tried..

```
[allViewControllers removeObjectIdenticalTo: @"NonLogginedViewController"];         
[allViewControllers removeObjectIdenticalTo: myDelegate.nonLogginedViewController];
myDelegate.navigationController.viewControllers = allViewControllers;
```

But it didn't update the `UINavigationController` stack ..
I don't know how to use `removeObjectIdenticalTo` with `UINavigationController` stack..

Please help me ..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Firstly, your test:

> [allViewControllers removeObjectIdenticalTo: @"NonLogginedViewController"];

...is testing for a string, not a view controller. So that won't work.

If you know where the view controller is in the navigation controller's stack then this is easy. Say for example you've just pushed a new controller and now you want to remove the one before that. You could do this:

```
NSMutableArray *allControllers = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
[allControllers removeObjectAtIndex:allControllers.count - 2];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:allControllers animated:NO];
```

But I think in your case you want to find a certain controller and remove it.  One way to do this would be to look for a certain class, e.g. LoginController. Set up a new array by copying the old one, and then iterate through this new array:

```
NSArray *allControllersCopy = [allControllers copy];

for (id object in allControllersCopy) {
   if ([object isKindOfClass:[LoginController class]])
      [allControllers removeObject:object];
}
```

...then set the allControllers array for the viewControllers property, as before.

NOTE: If you're manipulating a `UINavigationController`'s stack from a containing view controller – perhaps once that view controller appears – you should wait until the view is fully onscreen. A good place for that is in the `viewDidAppear:` override, for example:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated]; 
    NSMutableArray *allControllers = ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You saved my time..Thanks for giving  descriptive answer. It helped  me to   learn how to iterate NSMutablearry..

Comment: You can't do the bottom for loop as it invalidates the iterator

Comment: When / where should this code be executed?  I'm finding my nav tree gets messed up when it's done in viewWillAppear.

Comment: @capikaw viewWillAppear probably isn't a good place for that. The tree  may not have been finalised by that point. viewDidAppear or any time while the view is onscreen and not changing the tree is going to be ok.

Comment: Thank you very very much. Your last comment to your own answer was I was looking for. Please point that out in an *EDIT*. Not everyone will look all the way down to the last comment. Keep in mind that your last comment is a million times more valuable than your answer. In the answer you're just presenting basic arithmetic against a set of CocoaTouch collections which are rather general purpose language how to's.