# Delete actual navigationController and push to another one

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I've got 2 viewControllers A and B.

From controller A i want to push to controller B, and it;s work great.

Now in controller B I've got 'plus' button which push me to another B controller (the same ViewController). Now when im in secontr B viewController when i push back button i should be poped to A viewController. So i want to know how to remove ViewControler when i push another viewController?

Situation looks like this:

A (push B) -> B (push B) -> B (push B) -> B (pop B) -> A

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
id tempViewCont=nil;
for(id viewCont in [self.navigationController viewControllers])
{
   if([viewCont isKindOfClass:[A class]])
   {
      tempViewCont=viewCont;
      break;
   }
}

if(tempViewCont)
{
  [self.navigationController popToViewController:tempViewCont animated:yes]; 
}
```

Comment: @edzio27: Also if you have multiple A controllers in stack & you want to pop to later pushed A then you need to traverse loop in reverse order(You need to use for/while loop).

Comment: Thanks Ishu, for this. I also find help in this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099319/how-to-remove-a-particular-view-controller-from-uinavigationcontroller-stack

Answer (score 1):

Solution will be in `popToRootViewController:`
Call this method when you're done on B3 controller

So it will be:
 **A (pushViewController B1) -> B1 (pushViewController B2) -> B2 (pushViewController B3) -> B3 (popToRootViewController:) -> A**

Is that helps you?

Comment: my A controller is not a rootViewController so it doesnt work

Comment: So you might use this solution: `[self.navigationController popToViewController:A viewcontroller animated:yes];`

Answer (score 1):

Just try

```
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Or

```
  [self.navigationController popToViewController:A viewcontroller animated:yes];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following if you are pushing view controller A only once:

```
NSArray *tempArray = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
for (id viewController in tempArray) {
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:A]) {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:viewController animated:yes];
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 But, like the accepted answer, this finds the first occurrence of `A` and if you need the last, you'd have to tweak. And obviously if you wanted the first one, and that was the initial view controller, then you'd just do `popToRootViewControllerAnimated`.

Answer (score 0):

While all of the other answers are good, in my mind the question is whether you should be pushing from `B` to another copy of itself at all. For me, this is answered by the question of whether you ever want to pop from one `B` to the preceding `B`. If so, that's fine and use one of the other `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` or `popToViewController` answers when you want to go back to `A`.

If not, you simply shouldn't be pushing from `B` to another copy of itself at all. What you could do, though, if you want to present the user to demonstrate "let's do that again" button, you might use `transitionWithView`. For example, if we imagine that you have a bunch of `UITextField` controls on `B` and you have a "Add Another" button, it might do the following:

```
- (IBAction)onPressAddButton:(id)sender
{
    // save the record here

    // now, let's animate the resetting of the text fields

    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                      duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                    animations:^{
                        self.textField1.text = nil;
                        self.textField2.text = nil;
                        self.textField3.text = nil;
                    }
                    completion:nil];
}
```

And, by the way, if you do it this way, you now don't have to do anything fancy to get back from B back to A. The standard navigation bar does everything we need.